# Opengl 3.x ошибка gl.h included before glew.h

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Изучаю Opengl 3.x  в исходном коде урока произошла ошибка **gl.h included before glew.h**, из за чего не могу продолжать изучение.
уроки [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336166/)  самое интересное что предыдущий код урока работает отлично.

[Код главного файла](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/2.lighting/3.1.materials/materials.cpp)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <learnopengl/shader_m.h>
#include <learnopengl/camera.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f; 
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

// lighting
glm::vec3 lightPos(1.2f, 1.0f, 2.0f);

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader lightingShader("3.1.materials.vs", "3.1.materials.fs");
    Shader lampShader("3.1.lamp.vs", "3.1.lamp.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
    };
    // first, configure the cube's VAO (and VBO)
    unsigned int VBO, cubeVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // normal attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    // second, configure the light's VAO (VBO stays the same; the vertices are the same for the light object which is also a 3D cube)
    unsigned int lightVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &lightVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // note that we update the lamp's position attribute's stride to reflect the updated buffer data
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // be sure to activate shader when setting uniforms/drawing objects
        lightingShader.use();
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.position", lightPos);
        lightingShader.setVec3("viewPos", camera.Position);

        // light properties
        glm::vec3 lightColor;
        lightColor.x = sin(glfwGetTime() * 2.0f);
        lightColor.y = sin(glfwGetTime() * 0.7f);
        lightColor.z = sin(glfwGetTime() * 1.3f);
        glm::vec3 diffuseColor = lightColor   * glm::vec3(0.5f); // decrease the influence
        glm::vec3 ambientColor = diffuseColor * glm::vec3(0.2f); // low influence
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.ambient", ambientColor);
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.diffuse", diffuseColor);
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.specular", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // material properties
        lightingShader.setVec3("material.ambient", 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
        lightingShader.setVec3("material.diffuse", 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
        lightingShader.setVec3("material.specular", 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f); // specular lighting doesn't have full effect on this object's material
        lightingShader.setFloat("material.shininess", 32.0f);

        // view/projection transformations
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        lightingShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        lightingShader.setMat4("view", view);

        // world transformation
        glm::mat4 model;
        lightingShader.setMat4("model", model);

        // render the cube
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);


        // also draw the lamp object
        lampShader.use();
        lampShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        lampShader.setMat4("view", view);
        model = glm::mat4();
        model = glm::translate(model, lightPos);
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f)); // a smaller cube
        lampShader.setMat4("model", model);

        glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);


        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &lightVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, давай сначала. 
OpenGL Loading Library это библиотека которая загружает указатели на функции OpenGL, т.к. простой GL.h работает только с версией OpenGL 1.1. Проще говоря чтобы работать с другими версиями OpenGL тебе нужны специальные библиотеки которые откроют "возможности" других версий. Есть много библиотек, самые распространенные это Glad и Glew. 
В твоем случае это Glad, в моем примере это Glew. Ты не можешь использовать обе библиотеки т.к. они делают грубо говоря одно и тоже. Тебе надо выбрать одну из них. Удали всё что связано с Glew и добавь туда Glad.

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libglad.a")
#include <glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
```

Подробнее о библиотеках: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library

Comment: Я работаю с glew и glfv  подключаю вот так #include <gl/glfw3.h> в этом случаи всё работает, glad появилась в одном с уроков, я думал что это библиотека для роботы с материалами. Я пере прохожу курс уроков для полного понимания кода, glad я не компилировал, просто скинул файл glad/glad.h в  include визуал студио 10. теперь благодаря вам я понял в чем проблема, у меня исправлю отпишу.

Comment: Избавился от glad и все решилось. Одновременно подобные библиотеки использовать возможно! Видел уроки где использовали glew и glut, с возможностью переключиться между ними.

Answer (score 1):

Надо так:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32s.lib")
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
```

Comment: Обнаружил что у меня папки GLEW нету в библиотеках, исправлю отпишу.

Comment: 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\glad/glad.h(28): fatal error C1189: #error :  OpenGL header already included, remove this include, glad already provides it